# add the value stored in two linked lists and return a linked lists with the sum of the two numbers

Tags: linked-list, integer-overflow

my code seems to work, since it passes almost all the tests for this leetcode problem, however one of the tests is includes an extremely big value, which breaks my code.

the test case in particular that is breaking my code is

```
l1 = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
l2 = [5,6,4]
```

I understand what the problem is, the value is way to big to be stored in a long long int, but i don't know how to tackle this problem.

here is my code

```
#include <cmath>
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:

    vector<int> extractDigits(long long int num){
        vector<int> digits;

        if(num == 0){ //in case vector only contains 0 as its val 
            digits.push_back(num);
        }
        while (num != 0) {
            long long int digit = num % 10;
            digits.push_back(digit);
            num /= 10;
        }
        
        return digits;
    }

    void populateVector(vector<int> &vec, ListNode* list){
        while(list != NULL){
            
            vec.push_back(list->val);
            list = list->next;

        }
    }

    unsigned long long int vecToInt(vector<int> vec){
        int size = vec.size();
        int exp = size - 1;
        long long int num = 0;
        //cout<<size<<endl;
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){ //turns vector into number to be added
            unsigned long long int temp = 0;

            if(vec.at(x) != 0){
                temp = vec.at(x);
                temp = temp * pow(10,exp);
            }
            exp--;
            num += temp;
            


        }
        cout<<num<<endl;
        return num;
    }

    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* temp, asnwer;
        vector<int> digits1, digits2, sum;
        unsigned long long int number1 = 0 , number2 = 0;

    
        populateVector(digits1, l1);
        populateVector(digits2, l2);


        reverse(digits1.begin(), digits1.end());
        reverse(digits2.begin(), digits2.end());
        

        number1 = vecToInt(digits1);
        number2 = vecToInt(digits2);
    
        number1 += number2;
        //cout<<number1<<endl;
        sum = extractDigits(number1);

        ListNode* final_list = NULL;
        for(int digit : sum){
            if(!final_list){
                final_list = new ListNode(digit);
                temp = final_list;
            }
            else{
                temp->next = new ListNode(digit);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        return final_list;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you have a collection of ints you have most certainly misdiagnosed the problem.